# php settings on local vs production server (laravel)

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5, production-environment

I have made a laravel project where users can upload images. I have tested the project on local server and found nothing wrong. After uploading the project to the production server I found that, when a user tries to upload images that are greater than 1.5mb size, it shows error `TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67` although i have 
csrf token in my form. After couple of searching I found that some people are suggesting to change the two things in php.ini file and restart the nginx server. So I have changed the `post_max_size = 40M` `upload_max_filesize = 40M` and also changed the `max_execution_time = 0` which means unlimited execution time. Then I run this command `sudo service nginx restart` and `php artisan up` and tried to upload an image which is 21MB size. When I pressed the submit button, It took sometime to upload the image and eventually threw the token mismatch exception. I am using ubuntu 16.04 for local tests. Any solution to this problem please? 
I am sharing the codes:
view:

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=> "pro/{$user->id}/upload",'files'=> 'true', 'class'=> 'form-horizontal']) !!}

     <input id="filebutton" name="image" class="input-file" type="file">
     <input name="title" class="form-control" type="text" required="">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block btn-flat">Upload</button>
     {!! Form::close() !!}
```

controller:

```
public function save($id, PortfolioRequest $request)
  {
    $pro = User::findOrFail($id);
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $original_path = public_path('uploads/portfolio/original/');

    $file_name = str_random(64).'_'.$request->title.'_user_'. $pro->id . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    Image::make($file)
            ->resize(750,null,function ($constraint) {
              $constraint->aspectRatio();
               })
            ->save($original_path . $file_name);


    $portfolio = Portfolio::create([
      'user_id' => $id,
      'image'   => $file_name,
      'title'   => $request->title
    ]);

    return redirect("pro/{$id}/portfolio");
  }
```

the generated form:

```
<form method="POST" action="www.xxxx.com/pro/3/upload" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="EsH8KaSSoXovzjZ0RnWWi7eEwNWNgYlBVRm7yUYr">
```

Comment: The generated Form html how does the token look there?

Comment: @MartinHenriksen i have added that

Comment: Have before experienced Sessions messing up and creating a new session on the post request and therefor the tokens wont match.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your `<header>`:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```